# Launching custom chromecast receiver sometimes times out

Tags: android, chromecast

I have a custom Chromecast receiver that I launch from an Android app when the user selects their Chromecast device from the Cast button.  I find that I often get a timeout on the initial connection, but the second time it works fine.  Is the issue most likely my web server not responding fast enough, or are there other factors that might cause the timeout?

I'm getting the CastStatusCodes.TIMEOUT in onApplicationConnectionFailed().

My code to launch
(EDITED to include launchApplication)

```
Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext);
builder.addApi(Cast.API, apiOptionsBuilder.build());
builder.addConnectionCallbacks(this);
builder.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this);
mApiClient = builder.build();

if (mApiClient == null) return;
mApiClient.connect();

...

Cast.CastApi.launchApplication(mApiClient, mApplicationId)
 .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult>() {

    @Override
    public void onResult(ApplicationConnectionResult result) {
        if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            onApplicationConnected(
                result.getApplicationMetadata(),
                result.getApplicationStatus(),
                result.getSessionId(),
                result.getWasLaunched());
        } else {
                onApplicationConnectionFailed(result.getStatus().getStatusCode());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted is prior to loading the application so if you are getting a timeout in your onApplicationConnectionFailed, then it is further down in your code and not the part that you have posted here. If it is the loading of your application that fails, you need to check on your network and web server, etc.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the situation when receiver app **successfully**  launches after calling `launchApplication()` but `result.getStatus()` returns with TIMEOUT (instead of success)? Then receiver app closes after some time (due to no senders conncted to it).

Comment: If receiver gets the launch message, it will start the launch process and then responds to the sender; however if the response doesn't make it to the sender in time, sender considers that a timeout; in fact it wouldn't know the launch was successful or not since it didn't receive any message; so it is possible to see the app launched and yet sender throws a timeout error. I suggest you check your receiver log as well and see if there is anything there that can point you to the cause.